# Audio feedback while recording video

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, audio-recording, video-capture

I'm currently stuck on a problem, and Google doesn't seem to have anything for me.

I need to have the audio picked up by a webcam output to a pair of speakers plugged in the computer.

I know this isn't standard procedure and isn't easily feasible for a reason, but I can't get my superiors to drop this idea.

**Background :**
I'm working with desktop computer running ubuntu 18.04 and the webcam is a Logitech PTZ Pro 2

**The use case is as follows :**
The user needs to have the audio picked up by the webcam coming from his speakers at the same time they are capturing footage with audio from the webcam.

**What I've done so far :**
I've played around and finally got something approximately working using jackd, an additional mic, and its mixing capabilities, but it's not really user friendly and I've learned to treat users as child-like dumb humans. Problem is, while I've got it basically working, my recording software doesn't like it and freezes as soon as I click "Record".
I can't get anything working properly, and I can't get them to understand that it's not feasible or even worth our time for a single user doing that only once.

If you guys have any ideas, or if I'm doing something wrong, I'm open to ideas

**Edit for better understanding**

I have 3 different inputs :

1. Webcam's video
2. Webcam's audio
3. A button microphone (optional, because it's not needed, but could be added)

I have 2 output options :

1. Video on a computer monitor
2. Audio from a pair of external speakers

The webcam and the microphone would both be in the same room (R1), recording a subject (anything).
The user would be in another room (next to the first room, R2) with the computer, the screen and the speakers in front of him.

Before starting the recording, the user (located in R2) needs to be able to hear what's going on in R1, decide if everything is correctly setup for him, and then start the recording.
Once the recording is started, the user needs to have the audio from what's going on in R1 in real time. Ideally the audio would come from the webcam microphone, and be duplicated to the speakers and the recording.

I hope I managed to make this situation clearer

Answer (score 0):

Headset is your only 'fix'.

You cannot defy the laws of physics.
If you have a mic in the same area as speakers, with the sound from the mic routing to the speakers, you are going to get feedback.
This is a problem as old as amplification for live sound.

On large stages they have active feedback suppressors these days [not economical or indeed compatible with a consumer setup].
The alternative is to face the speakers away from the mic with as great a distance as you can physically achieve, then use a directional mic, also pointing away from the speakers. You don't want any walls or hard surfaces in proximity to either, for several reasons - bass-lift/proximity effect & simple reflection.

You will get exactly the same issue - except far worse, as you're not even getting the slight delay or fall-off that the speaker-mic distance would give you - if you attempt similar routing inside your computer.

You see why a headset is easier?

Otherwise, don't feed the mic to the speakers at all.

Comment: My bad, it seems I didn't explain things properly. The computer and the webcam are both in different rooms. The user needs to be able to hear the audio picked up from the webcam before recording, and while recording as well. Maybe "feedback" isn't the correct word in this case

Comment: The location of the computer is unimportant; only the relative positions of mic & speakers, & whether the voiceover is going back through the nearby speakers. You may need to better explain the setup.

Comment: See my answer, the text was too long for a comment

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I figured it would be too vague with my explaining.

I have 3 different inputs :

1. Webcam's video
2. Webcam's audio
3. A button microphone (optional, because it's not needed, but could be added)

I have 2 output options :

1. Video on a computer monitor
2. Audio from a pair of external speakers

The webcam and the microphone would both be in the same room (R1), recording a subject (anything).
The user would be in another room (next to the first room, R2) with the computer, the screen and the speakers in front of him.

Before starting the recording, the user (located in R2) needs to be able to hear what's going on in R1, decide if everything is correctly setup for him, and then start the recording.
Once the recording is started, the user needs to have the audio from what's going on in R1 in real time. Ideally the audio would come from the webcam microphone, and be duplicated to the speakers and the recording.

I hope I managed to make this situation clearer

Comment: You really need to edit this into your question to make one coherent request. It's not an answer so doesn't belong in the answer space.